# ¿Como evitar que se llame a otros oyentes del mismo evento, de manera correcta?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy trabajando con varios SELECT que se encuentran en diferentes tablas y necesito que cuando se haga un cambion en la opción seleccionada ocurra un evento, el problema, es que pueden ser N SELECTS y como pueden estar en diferentes tablas necesito que el cambio solo se refleje en la tabla Padre y en el  del SELECT seleccionado. Además de que puedo agregar nuevas filas, añadiendo así aun mas SELECTS a una tabla. Después de probar con varios métodos encontré el Event.stopImmediatePropagation() y este ha resultado funcionar dado que evita que se creen mas llamados del mismo evento a un elemento. Mi problema es que cuando agrego una nueva fila el ultimo SELECT agregado funciona correctamente, pero todos los demás tienen un problema el cual es que al cambiar de opción, por ejemplo: de la opción 1 a la opción 2, este, visualmente sigue mostrando la opción 1 y hay que darle clic al SELECT otra vez, sin necesidad de volver seleccionar la opción 2, para que visualmente quede marcada. Esto solo empezo a ocurrir al implementar el Event.stopImmediatePropagation(), entonces ¿Estoy evitando correctamente que se llamen otros oyentes del mismo evento?

#### Funcion para inicializar y que reaccione a los cambios en la pantalla

```
let recetas = document.querySelector('#recetas-container').addEventListener('change', event => {
        this.calcularPorcentajeMezcla();
        this.PruebaCambio();
    });
```

#### Funcion para recorrer las tablas y agregarle el evento de CHANGE a los select

```
private PruebaCambio() {
    let recetas = document.querySelectorAll('.receta');
    recetas.forEach(receta => {
        let tabla = '#data-table-' + receta.id + ' tbody';
        $(tabla).find('.clases-options').on('change', event => {
            let selectClase = document.getElementsByClassName('clases-options');
            let algo = document.getElementsByName(event.target.attributes[1].nodeValue);
            console.log("Entre");
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });            
    });

}
```

Agradezco la a quien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: event.stopPropagation()